# rCharts:rPlot() Fewer colors than levels

Tags: r, rcharts

I try this:

```
testd <- data.frame(ID=1:10,cl=sample(1:10,100,replace=TRUE),x=runif(100),y=2*runif(100))
testd$ID <- factor(testd$ID)
testd$cl <- factor(testd$cl)
levels(testd$cl)
rPlot(y~x, data = testd, color = 'cl', 
      tooltip = "#!function(item){ return 'cl: ' + item.cl + ' id: ' + item.ID }!#",
      type = 'point', ylim=c(-0.5,1.5))
```

But I get a legend with only 4 levels (2,4,6,8), while I have 10 levels in cl
Why?
Also, I do not get to control the axes limits.

Any help appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: I think you may want `cl=rep(1:10,10)` instead of using `sample`. `sample` will randomly pick values in `1:10`, it doesn't have to take all of them (and therefore not all colors appear).

Comment: Vincent,sample(1:10,100,replace=TRUE) is correct, I just create 100 integers between 1 and 10 with repetition. Note levels(testd$cl) correctly prints the 10 labels. I do have a typo in ID=1:10 which should be ID=1:100, but this does not have any effect on the colors. Thanks.

Comment: But you want each cl level to be associated with 1 ID ?

Comment: No. The ID is just to identify the individual (row) in the plot. I check with the tooltip class (cl) and individual (ID). Color refers to cl only.

Comment: The trouble is that polychart is intepreting `cl` as numeric. I believe this is a bug (or a feature) in polycharts. There is a way to specify the column classes explicitly while loading data in polycharts, but that feature is currently not implemented in rCharts.

Comment: Therefore no way to get correct colors for categorical variables? no workaround?